# Setstate of specific object in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I have a cats array that I pull from an api

i map over these and render them on a page

each one gets rendered with a like button, when I hit like I want it to like it and when i hit like again, it should unlike it

my initialState is :

```
  state = {
    cats: []
  };
```

then once i call the api state looks like this:

```
cats: [
    {url: Array(1), id: Array(1), source_url: Array(1), liked: false}
    {url: Array(1), id: Array(1), source_url: Array(1), liked: false}
]
```

I have a like cat method whereby I find the cat that I liked like this:

`var cat = this.state.cats.find(c => c.id[0] === cat.id[0])`

considering I have all this information, how do I call setState for that specific cat to change the `liked` from false to true?

I was thinking something like this:

```
   this.setState(prevState => ({ cats: {
      cat: {
        ...prevState.cat,
        liked: !prevState.cat.liked
      }
    }}))
```

but it does not know what `liked is of undefined`

any ideas?

Comment: Is it obverses? Should be `prevState.cat[0].liked`. What is `cat.id[0]` in `var cat = this.state.cats.find(c => c.id[0] === cat.id[0])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your approach is that there's no `prevState.cat`.

Assuming the (un)liked cat is stored in `cat`:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
    cats: prevState.cats.map(c => c.id[0] === cat.id[0] ? Object.assign(c, { liked: !c.liked }) : c)
}));
```

Demo:

```js
var state;

function setState(a) {
  state = Object.assign(state, a(state));
}

state = {
  cats: [
      {url: [0], id: [1], source_url: [0], liked: false},
      {url: [0], id: [2], source_url: [0], liked: false}
  ]
};

var cat = state.cats[1];
setState(prevState => ({
  cats: prevState.cats.map(c => c.id[0] === cat.id[0] ? Object.assign(c, { liked: !c.liked }) : c)
}));

console.log(state.cats[1].liked);
```

Comment: when using prevstate should you mutate the state directly ?

Comment: @Omar You're right, one shouldn't. Fixed my answer.

Comment: just so im clear, you map over the array of cats, you find the one by matching the ids, and then you change the `liked` key for that cat with object.assign so as to not mutate it directly?

Comment: @TheWalrus Exactly, but `map()` creates a copy, so I'm never mutating `prevState`, not even indirectly.

Comment: this is a much better implementation